# How can we send Jenkins generated Performance Report in email body (post build action)

Tags: html, jenkins, groovy, jmeter, performance-testing

There is a Performance Report generated at the end of Load Test on Jenkins and I want to send it in email body.

I tried to use `img alt="" src="https://abcabc.com/abc/abcd"/>` in the Jenkins Pipeline, but the image is broken in email. Here I cannot change Jenkins configurations.

Please let me know if there is alternate solution

Answer (score 0):

after your test executed please copy paste the report in userContent folder explicitly in Jenkins.
then attach the file from userContent location in your email body .
This should resolve your problems.

Note : grant overall read access to anonymous user if you want to access the image from current location.
basically the report is stored in job workspace folder, which can only be accessed by using your Jenkins credentials